# Passport local strategy not authenticate

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

My callback successfully called when I try to login and I got `SUCCESS` message. But I still redirected to login page.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
function(username, password, done) {

        console.log(username + "----" + password)

        if(username == "test" && password == "test"){
            console.log("SUCCESS")
            done(null, { name: username})
        }
        else{
            done(null, false)
        }
}))
```

My routes are defined in next order

```
 .. some othe initialization, cookieparser, bodyparser, session ...
 app.use(passport.initialize())
 app.use(passport.session())

 app.use('/login', login);


 app.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
       res.redirect('/plans');
    });

app.all('*',function (req, res, next) {

   console.log(req.isAuthenticated())
   if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
       return next()
   }
   res.redirect('/login')
})

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/plans', plans);
```

Are there any mistake here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A possible cause could be the following:

In my node application, I have the following middleware:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    cookie: {  httpOnly: true,  secure: true  }
}));
```

The following line always returns false:

```
req.isAuthenticated()
```

When I change secure's value from true to false. The issue goes away.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit of a shot in the dark but do you need a successRedirect on top of the failureRedirect? I think you are being authed correctly but the route then doesn't know what to do after the success so it simply defaults to whatever pathways are available. As I said, this is a guess but seems plausible.

Let me know.

Just to show an example from the passport documentation:

```
app.post('/login',
passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                               failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

Source: http://passportjs.org/docs

Also, if you want to authenticate and then have it fall through to the actual route function you are passing in then I think you want to remove the redirects all together.

```
app.post('/login',
passport.authenticate('local'),
function(req, res) {
   // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
   // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
});
```

Also from the documentation.

Best,
Runner5

Comment: I have already tryed above but this doesn't help. I am still not authenticated, even after login attempt I try to access any resource

Comment: How are you authing the user requests? Are you using a token system or session system? I think you are actually getting authed successfully shown by getting the success console log in auth strategy. The question is why is not being respected on subsequent requests. I would assume the appropriate auth info isn't being passed for the requests being made.